# Powershell - import csv based on variable in a list

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to import csv rows based on the value of a cell using powershell.  I would like to store the desired import values in a text file (or some other file) so that they can be easily adjusted by the end user.  There may be up to 20 values in the list - eg in the example below I would need -or for all values from 'Text1' to 'Text20'.

```
     Import-Csv $sourcecsv.csv | where {$_.column -eq 'Text1' -or $_.column -eq 'Text2'} |
     Export-CSV $outputcsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks

Comment: What does `sourcecsv.csv` look like?

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: `$_.column -eq 'Text1' -or $_.column -eq 'Text2'` and `$_.column -in 'Text1','Text2'` are equivalent…

Answer (score 0):

You could put your search terms on separate lines in a file:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

Then read them in using `Get-Content` and use the `-contains` or `-in` operators to check if the column value matches:

```bsh
$searchTerms = Get-Content list.txt
Import-Csv $sourcecsv.csv | Where { $_.column -in $searchTerms }
```